# Katalon recorder try multiple selectors

Tags: katalon-recorder, katalon

Inside one of the steps I have multiple  tags like

```
<option>link=storage locker for ${uniqueName}</option>
<option>//a[contains(text(),'storage locker for ${uniqueName}')]</option>
```

I noticed that depending on the browser OS the second version works better. Is there a way to force Katalon to try each option?